# Неправильная кодировка json файла при считывании его из jar-файлы

Tags: java, jar, кодировка

Вобщем есть такой код:

```
public File getResource(String resourceName) {
    File jarFile = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());

    if (jarFile.isFile()) {  // Run with JAR file
        JarFile jar = null;
        try {
            jar = new JarFile(jarFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries(); //gives ALL entries in jar
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            final String name = entries.nextElement().getName();
            if (name.startsWith(resourceName + "/")) { //filter according to the path
                System.out.println(name);
            }
        }
        try {
            jar.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else { // Run with IDE
        jarFile = new File(ResourceLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName).getFile());
    }


    return jarFile;
}
```

Ним я считываю файлы из папки **src/resources** , проблемы возникают при считывании `.json` файла: когда я запускаю через IDE - содержимое файла считывается нормально, когда же я запускаю код используя `.jar` то при считывании содержимое получается в непонятной кодировке.

Вот так я считываю содержимое файла:

```
 public String loadResourceFile(String resourceFileName) {

        File file = getResource(resourceFileName);

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),"utf-8"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                stringBuilder.append(ls);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                assert reader != null;
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

> "�│�#,F��M�·��2��N�%��·3␊V�
>                              ˷�≤��)"�·��+����У ���Ë� £�│�␉눚+π��םΣ�����@�
>                                                                          � ␌4◆+≠⎼�ܣ<����°�[�┤␍\� ��՝����┌Ӻ���Ғ+�A ␋6R�.�Ԡ�
>   ���:���D�ˆZ$�ᆌ�'3�6��:2�6�O1S��┤*>�;�<꼬)ㇼ│O=����>TW�5�┴GS*��Z*9#--�&3°͚E8��πQK��LS��9��6;�─P��*F<��I≤�└�≠�Z
>   ≤]│�� �5�└Y�8�A��┌��·�Z(���ˊI����D3␉�21�≤2���M␌"��M6<��┬⎼\��J��F����
>   :��-*␌·���L�X≥��J�( ≥N�πE��W�暮T�F�[^�≤��6*�┼�ٔ�S�0��;�
>                                      \����°��� ␌4���2��R��┘$�°,�≥°�⎻��D��␉�␤�_6��]07LDY#����├����>���␍�▒�ʾ�│�H֒�RF
>   ���ىP7�^��X£R��─ֵE���≥ £-��<��┐���)��=��ͧ?�I���@?�*
>
> ␉JS?����@���C�������ف�⎻▒�▒▒�������� \M�@�b{?.
>                                                 9�h�b��0V�a��q��!�~��g��R�."�5�6}��O�{1h�5���ZQ'�a�����V�w�Z��S~ȓ��Z{d!=TM/,�$,�T,�t,�,�~���[)1��W�iL؎s//S?:��4����65T�@~��0�ڰ�
>   �   FĆqU��ίj
>   ُ��P�ٵ≤^������┴۹,@<␍�,⎻��H.⎻��0�����·��⎽�·���␊�≠7���LW/┼T/N�����<~O�݋�ps�ŷ������^jG�]}�'���X7}�h�>�}M~���}���ʬ��qstt+3R>9�x�zs��|p�̚Oev~�?~w3��3Gak
>   ����x�\�a��0dKu�B�"�N��]�>���   ^���}�!3�l���ncО@/e}�a����s�N*�c·�y
>                                                                       ��2n���Lvmr5��u{�/r�3���"�d �����▒�����L��L�-݊��M��π└Y�°┌F
>                                 �┼�S��Ũ─��߀�H��␤�������£� �}��fZ~
>                                                                  ��p����>��^���n�����
>                                                                                      |D�p�\��҂�)�L��Rs�қ� �O���������|G��a�+���RG�0�o��?�෗:Ԭc��)��;�
>   W���+�J]\�Py ��m�Y���R�q�T�Ļ<�*�N-e>��I�[�<�ǜ��"|�c��l������I�}��>�
>   <�Yx��>��1�?Ýg^�d3O�y\�8��A|����~�v� ^o�?��L"�R^Pه7*��v
>   W��2���8�TՏ6pzU~Ri�����>�r��;�@U�8=<���ڝ�d'C�3�2�7
>   ��+���&X����S�����az���#(�0W=�����/#��8Gp�h/LǸ�qz�OZ�XN�jj86��N�o���7��Uel09����
>   �+�1����������a֔�e���^V����+,hk�k��B�r�k�=������;��7��wY�L�R�bxW
>   �ׇ?n�9��
>                                                                            �n����Z�-A'�UH��
>                                                                                             ����kV���-��Ce�IL�?��)�8���~�U��U
>                                                                                                                              ��JQ<�(e�VS�j�zuV�6P�5�X����MM�n�:�6�֎?1��Կp�
>   ���1��I�����Y6��l����⠪}���
>   9D\"$�`��+���A)��q(�i����<�e�;N�)n��驾�X5Q#�r*V���8�L����Xp@&<5"�S��L���L�G���S�{s�+�N)̚y�*8�a&/%�7*�dJ��g<�����/2��?�nQ�'5ϡZ���g,.��[x�Z<��ϧj�R��v�
>                                                                                                                                                        �2.$��O4e��*�'ӟ9��T����e�b,�"C�G;,�6F=(���dʻ�+���
>                               f �̀���2�'��X,s�L�b-��2�d��K�U������b�����9��u+�:(�
>                                                                                        ʂ��A       �ˢ�AY��/KÕ£��␊��
>                                                                                                                   �9�⎺����U��V\�π����H�.├����Z─'Y␊6 X#�┤OG���:�
>   ��▒�����X�␉Y�����2␍°�⎼,◆��\V◆%�)˫�?�␊�K�UٵA�G5┘��C◆I:�<,�U�␊��0V�I�MB�����⎼�␉A├├⎼▒␌├␋⎽-M▒␌B⎺⎺┐-P⎼⎺:┌␋␉⎽
>   ┐␋⎼≤▒46$

вывожу содержимое файла

```
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();
    String resource = resourceLoader.loadResourceFile("imgs.json");

    JSONObject object = null;
    try {

    object = new JSONObject(resource);
    }catch (JSONException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage())
    }
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Покажите что получается и что ожидаете. Возможно вы храните json в UTF-8, а Java по-умолчанию читает их в UTF-16

Comment: _при считывании содержимое получается в непонятной кодировке_ Как вы определяете, что именно при считывании, а не при выводе?

Comment: @tutankhamun добавил в вопрос

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я понятия не имею, может и при записи

Comment: Распакуйте и посмотрите на файлы - в какой они кодировке и приведите тот фрагмент, который вы прислали в читаемом виде

Comment: @tutankhamun charset=us-ascii, код добавил

Comment: Вообще говоря правильный json не зависит от кодировок(состоит исключительно из первой половины православного ASCII). У вас нечто бинарное прочиталось. Может zip? В смысле, распаковать забыли?

Comment: @vp_arth очень может быть, я уже кажется понял где может быть ошибка, надо проверить...

Comment: Если не изменяет мне память, то `getResourceAsStream("/resources/imgs.json")` в обоих случаях вернёт "правильный" поток